# How can I clean up Channels on disconnect for tokio/tonic?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-tonic

I am implementing a turn-based game server using `tonic`. I use gRPC streaming for the game so that players get sent updates about the moves their opponents make once they connect, more or less like this (simplified):

```
service Game {
    rpc Connect(ConnectRequest) returns (stream CommandList);
    rpc PerformAction(GameRequest) returns (CommandList);
}
```

The way I currently handle this is that I store a `Sender` object for each player that connects, so that I can update them later:

```rust
static CHANNELS: Lazy<DashMap<PlayerId, Sender<Result<CommandList, Status>>>> = (...)

#[tonic::async_trait]
impl MyGame for GameService {
    type ConnectStream = ReceiverStream<Result<CommandList, Status>>;

    async fn connect(
        &self,
        request: Request<ConnectRequest>,
    ) -> Result<Response<Self::ConnectStream>, Status> {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(4);
        // Store channel to provide future updates:
        CHANNELS.insert(player_id, tx);
        Ok(Response::new(ReceiverStream::new(rx)))
    }
}
```

This way, when game actions come in, I can check the `CHANNELS` map to see which opponents are connected and send them an update with the new game state:

```rust
async fn perform_action(
    &self,
    request: Request<GameRequest>,
) -> Result<Response<CommandList>, Status> {
    if let Some(channel) = CHANNELS.get(&player_id) {
        // Send update to opponent
    }
}
```

This approach is generally working quite well. One immediate problem, however, is that the `CHANNELS` map grows infinitely in size as players connect, I haven't been able to find an explicit callback in `tonic` when users disconnect from their gRPC streaming session where I could clean up the map. Does something like that exist? Alternatively, is this a complete misuse of the API and I should be doing something totally different? :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with tonic or grpc, but if tonic is using http2 under the hood, I doubt there's a concept of a "connection", given that HTTP requests are independent of each other.